# How can I implement GameCenter using c++ on ios platform

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I am currently using Xcode 4.2 and ios 5. I need a way to implement Game Center for my game. But my game is programmed in c++. Problem is, every tutorial on Game Center i have seen so far, the GameCenter is implemented on Objective-c. Pls Advice how can I implement GameCenter using c++ on ios platform?

Answer (score 1):

You must implement the interaction with game center in objc. What you can do is create a single object that handles game center in a objc++ file (.mm). There you can call your c++ code and forward all requests/data.

Comment: I am trying to port code from GKtapper to my c++. Is it possible? i am trying to do this because they have already implement game center in Objective-c.

Comment: but right now problem i faced is my c++ code is unable to get instance of gamecenter because it is objc instance

Comment: That is why you need to use .mm so you can mix objc and c++. Some parts must be implemented in objc.

Comment: did u mean i should change extension from .cpp to .mm?  I avoid to do that on request of client